# Long Press gesture and movement of uiimageview?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, long-press

I have a `UIImageView` with a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` that sends an action when a long press is detected.

I do have user interaction enabled on the `UIImageView`. However, I also have a sort of manual scrolling where the `UIImageView` can be moved using the `touchesBegan` and `touchesMoved` methods.

When the user interaction is disabled, only the scrolling works. When the user interaction is enabled, only the long press gesture recognizer works.

How can I make it so that both will work simultaneously?

Code can be shared if necessary, but I don't think this problem requires it.

Answer (score 3):

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] init];
[gestureRecognizer addTarget:self action:@selector(imgLongPressed:)];
gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
[imgview addGestureRecognizer: gestureRecognizer];

- (void) imgLongPressed:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)sender
{
    UIImageView *view_ =(UIImageView*) sender.view;
    CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:view_.superview];

    if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
    {

    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
    {

    }
    else if (sender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Gesture recognizers always take priority and override `touchesBegan:` style events. You will have to implement both behaviours using the same API/technique.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will have to use gesture for moving the image like below.

```
 UIPanGestureRecognizer  *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(move:)];
[panRecognizer setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setMaximumNumberOfTouches:1];
[panRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[vwBigImage addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
```

the function which will be called is like below..

```
 -(void)move:(id)sender {

CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:yourview];

if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
    _firstX = [yourimageview center].x;//declare CGFloat _firstX; in .h file

    _firstY = [yourimageview center].y;//declare CGFloat _firstY; in .h file
}

translatedPoint = CGPointMake(_firstX+translatedPoint.x, _firstY+translatedPoint.y);
[yourimageview setCenter:translatedPoint];

}
```

Now your both gestures will be called.

Let me know it is working or not!!!

Happy coding!!!!